# C program that uses functions to read the array elements inputted by the user and then swap them

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm currently taking an accelerated C introductory course, so most of my learning is coming from message boards and online resources. I'm having trouble getting my code to output, i think the issue is with my swap_array.

Hi all, I've deleted my original code (don't know if this is encouraged, but just for the sake of clarity). Thanks for the comments. It was a mess so I wanted to edit and post my updated code but I'm not sure how to format the swaparray function below the main. Basically, I want the function to be able to swap the values in list 1 and 2 when called to do so in the main.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fillarray(int list[], int size);
void printarray(int list1[], int list2[]);
void swaparray(int list1[], int list2[], int size);

int main()
{
    int a[5], b[5];
    int size = 5;

    fillarray(a, size);
    fillarray(b, size);

    printf("List1 and List2 before the swap\n");
    printf("List1\t\t\t\List2\n");

    printarray(a, b);
    swaparray(a, b, size);

    printf("List1 and List2 before the swap\n");
    printf("List1\t\t\t\List2\n");

    printarray(a, b, size);

    return 0;
}
 //////FUNCTIONS////////

void fillarray(int list[], int size)
{
    printf("Please enter 5 values for the array\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    scanf_s("%d", &list[i]);
    }
}

void printarray(int list1[], int list2[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t\t\t %d", list1[i], list2[i]);

    }
}

void swaparray(int list1[], int list2[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: By "swap", do you mean "reverse"?

Comment: The code doesn't compile; you've not defined `array1` or `array2` (nor `print1` nor `print2`) in `main()`.  Your function declarations take integers, not arrays.  You can't subscript plain integers . Please post code that compiles!

Comment: 1. Please format the code consistently, use indentation correctly and use white spaces to separate visually the different "_tokens_" of the program, we unlike compilers have a hard time reading `x,y` instead of `x, y`. 2. State a clear problem definition, it's not possible to understand what is bad in the output. Describe clearly what you want the code to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help step-by-step and explain how you can get this to compile and run, and try to help you understand what's going on.

On line 4, you are declaring the `swap_array` function which currently takes as input 3 int variables. However, you want to pass in arrays instead (so you can swap them) for the first two parameters using the `[]` notation (e.g. `int array1[]`). The same goes for the `print_array` function just below. You also need to do this in the definitions of those functions (on line 21 and 34).

Let's look at the main function now. You are currently creating `array` in the main function. Great. That's fine. However, straight after, you are calling `swap_array` with arguments `array1` and `array2`. You have not declared and initialised these two variables in your main function, so your program has no idea what to do.

So what you need to do in main is create two arrays, `array1` and `array2` (similar to how you do it for array) and then feed those into the swap_array function.

Finally, you are calling print_array with arguments `print1` and `print2`. Again, these variables are nowhere to be seen in your main. What exactly do you want to print? You want to print the two arrays you have just swapped: `array1` and `array2`. Therefore these need to be the arguments that you feed into the print function, not `print1` and `print2`.

I think you are getting confused between the difference between parameters and arguments. On lines 3, 4, 5, 21, 34 and 47, you have declared/defined functions. In these functions are the parameters. These parameters are used directly within the function as part of your calculations. Think of them as 'placeholders' for real values. When you call a function (e.g. in main), you can set these parameter values to whatever you want (e.g. value or the value of a variable), and these are called arguments (as you do in lines 15, 16 and 17).

I hope this helps. You should be able to compile and run with these changes.

Comment: Yes I was getting confused on when to define and when to call, we had about 5 minutes of instruction and I was hoping someone would give me concise feedback as I know my skills are very lacking. Thanks so much for the help,

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that by swap you meant reverse, to accomplish your task I'd use stack, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* stderr, fprintf, printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, abort, free */

int * stack;        /* stack array */

int main(void) {    /* remember about void! */
    int size, i;    /* variable holding size and stack pointer, could name it better */

    printf("Amount of elements:"); /* ask for amount of elements */
    scanf("%d", &size);            /* size now contains it */

    stack = malloc(sizeof(int) * size); /* allocate enough memory */

    if(!stack) {  /* succeed? */
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory."); /* no, print error */
        abort(); /* bail out */
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size;) { /* now, read stack */
        scanf("%d", &stack[i++]);
    }

    printf("Reversed:\n");

    for(i = size; i > 0;) { /* and print it from the back */
        printf("%d\n", stack[--i]);
    }

    free(stack);
}
```

Please remember to validate user input (I didn't include that; it may be your exercise).

Comment: You seem to be fond of posting your own solutions, without answering the question.

Comment: I used comments to clarify what exactly the code is doing.

Comment: That may be so, but you don't address the faults in the OP's code. This might be a very good solution, but it is not an answer.

Comment: I don't like adressing mistakes in someones code and fixing it because most communities i had contact with dont like that approach

Comment: That is what this site is for: addressing the problems of OP code. Providing a copy/paste solution is of no real help. Like "give him a fish", or "teach him to fish".

Comment: @WeatherVane well, the code consists mainly of errors like undeclared variables.
There is no clear need to explain it. My algo in op's use case is better, so I didn't take on revising original.

Comment: I have no doubt you are a better programmer than OP. But are you a good teacher, or good at demonstrating your skill?